# Can a set of vectors span P2 and P3? If a set of vectors does not include a value for X^3, but spans P2, can it still span P3?

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, vector-spaces

Given these four vectors, x^2 + x, 2x^2, 2x-3, 9, I have determined they are linearly dependent and that they form a vector equation of

C1 + 2c2 = 0

C1 + 2c3 = 0

-3c3 + 9c4 = 0

Which I think has an infinite solutions…
I’m confused whether they span P3 or not. Or if it’s possible for them to span P3 given (1,x,x^2,x^3) isn’t possible.

Comment: To span $P3$ some linear combination would have to yield $x^3$. You seem to know whether that can happen.

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation) whenever you type a formula on this site. It’s pretty easy. You just enclose your formulae into the $ signs, for the most part.

Answer (score 0):

They can in general, but in your specific case they can't because they cannot generate $x^3$.

Perhaps, to expand on this, you may also be interested in an answer to the question: what is the meaning of $x$? Here is one possible explanation in the case of real polynomials. (See also [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/495465/what-is-an-indeterminate-in-a-polynomial-ring), and a more advanced discussion [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/33865/indeterminate-x-in-algebra-ring-theory).): If $V$ is the vector space of all infinite real sequences with operations defined naturally, we let:

$$1=(1,0,0,\cdots),$$
$$x=(0,1,0,0,\cdots),$$
$$x^2=(0,0,1,0,0,\cdots),$$
$$x^3=(0,0,0,1,0,0,\cdots),$$ and so on. The vector space obtained by the span of $\{1,x,x^2,\cdots,x^n\}$ is the vector space $P_n$.

Now

$$x^2+x=(0,1,1,0,0,\cdots),$$
$$2x^2=(0,0,2,0,0,\cdots),$$
$$2x-3=(-3,2,0,0,\cdots),$$
$$9=(9,0,0,\cdots)$$

and it is easily seen there is no way that any linear combination of the above can yield a non-zero value at the fourth position. Hence these cannot generate $x^3$. It follows that these vectors cannot span $P_3$.